# Qual melhor opção para proteger diretórios e arquivos em uma pasta raiz?

Tags: apache, htaccess, aplicação-web, diretório

Em um servidor web, eu tenho uma pasta dentro da pasta raiz (public_html) que deve ser protegida. Nela contém arquivos do sistema, configurações, logs, classes e etc...

De forma genérica, qual a melhor opção para proteger o acesso à pasta, a qualquer arquivo contido nela e a todos os seus subdiretórios?

Comment: Desculpa, mas da para pormenorizar um bocadinho mais ? Acerca de como está(ão) estruturada(s) essas pastas ?

Answer (score 2):

Exemplos.

Alterar arquivo `httpd.conf` ou `apache2.conf`.

Para bloquear acesso a arquivos com extensão `.conf` e `.log`.

```
<Files ~ "(.conf|.log)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Para bloquear um diretório que está localizado no DocumentRoot (não sei se é isso que você pretende fazer):

```
<Directory "/var/www/Projeto/configuracoes">
    deny from all
</Directory>
```

Referências e outros links úteis:

[Pete Freitag - 20 ways to Secure your Apache Configuration](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm)

[Stackoverflow - htaccess  deny from all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683496/htaccess-directory-deny-from-all)

Answer (score 1):

Coloque os arquivos de sistema num diretório sem acesso público

Exemplo

O *DocumentRoot* está definido em `/var/www/site/public_html/`

Então basta colocar os arquivos dos sistema em qualquer outro diretório que não esteja público. Exemplo `/var/www/site/app/`

Então dentro desse diretório ficaria algo assim
`/var/www/site/app/core/`
`/var/www/site/app/libs/`
`/var/www/site/app/vendor/`

No diretório `/var/www/site/public_html/`, obviamente você terá o index.php.
No arquivo index.php basta incluir os arquivos de sistema fazendo o recuo de diretório.

Exemplo: `include __DIR__.'/../app/Core/Core.php';`.

Arquivos do tipo log, podem ficar em outro local

Ao invés de `/var/www/site/app/logs`, sugiro `/var/www/site/logs/`.

Um motivo é que quando precisar fazer um backup da pasta `app`, não precisará se preocupar em pular os arquivos de log ou outros desnecessários.